# Is there a database/table browser for delta lake?

Tags: delta-lake

Is there a tool that acts like a database/table browser for delta lake?
We have an open source deployment of delta.io and was wondering if there was any tooling available that gives a nicer developer experience similar to SSMS, MySQL Workbench, DBeaver, etc.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I got things to work partially with DBeaver.
I started the Apache Thrift Server on my delta lake container which exposed jdbc over port 10000.
Was able to use the Apache Spark connection with DBeaver with JDBC URL jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000.
This lets DBeaver populate the list of databases and tables. However Columns do not show up. This got me a better developer experience than Jupyter. If anyone can get columns to show as well, please post your solution.